# Скачать файл .pdf из облака и вывести страницу в среде Python

Tags: python-3.x, изображения, pdf, google-drive

Всем доброго дня.

У меня на гуглодиске есть папка ID123. В папке два файла: ID123_counts.xls и layout.pdf;
Файл ID123_counts.xls я скачиваю и открываю функцией

```
def get_gspread(table, sheet, index_col='Sample', path_to_json=None):

    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    import gspread

    if path_to_json == None:
        path_to_json = 'my_json/google_secret.json'

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        path_to_json)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    wks = gc.open(table)
    sheet = wks.worksheet(sheet)
    data = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())
    data = data.set_index(index_col)
    return data
```

Получаю pd.DataFrame
Вопрос: как мне также открыть файл layout.pdf? Просто как бы как питоновский график?
На страницах файла нету текста, посему сразу уточняю, что решения типа *extractText()* мне не подходят:

```
from PyPDF2 import PDFFileReader
pdf_file = open('document_path.PDF', 'rb')
PDF_read = PDFFileReader(pdf_file)
first_page = PDF_read.getPage(0)
print(first_page.extractText())
```

На страницах файла находится пара графиков, мне нужно их просто вывести

Comment: Попробуйте решения из этого вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470099/view-pdf-image-in-an-ipython-notebook

Comment: Спасибо, хорошее решение. Но это не отвечает на вопрос, как скачать pdf с облака google drive((